# How do I get rid of istartsurf browser hijacker

Tags: firefox, malware-removal

My Firefox browser has become infected with the istartsurf hijacker, which means that an istartsurf tab is added to my browser's tabs each time I start Firefox. How do I get rid of it?

**What I already did/tried**

- Remove istartsurf with Revo Uninstaller
- Remove all instances of istartsurf files on my system disk
- Remove all references to istartsurf in the registry
- Restored startup options in Firefox
- Remove all references to istartsurf in Firefox settings ("about.config")

Doesn't seem to be sufficient, though; the tab still gets added. What else needs to be done?

PS: On [this site](https://malwaretips.com/blogs/remove-istartsurf-virus/) they suggest resetting Firefox to its default state, but I'd like to avoid that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I remove malicious spyware, malware, adware, viruses, trojans or rootkits from my PC?](http://superuser.com/questions/100360/how-can-i-remove-malicious-spyware-malware-adware-viruses-trojans-or-rootkit)

Comment: @DavidPostill - I'm not sure the answers there are the right ones for my question. Sure there must be less dramatic ways that to reinstall my OS.

Comment: <shrug>. You could have done some research and found [How to remove iStartSurf.com virus (Removal Guide)](https://malwaretips.com/blogs/remove-istartsurf-virus/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems I forgot one thing: the shortcut for Firefox was edited as well. Trim it to just the path+filename and you're all set.

[image]